# Android OnClickListener change button text or show progres

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, progress, settext

I am trying to set the text of the button before I save the file. The file takes awhile to save. So when the button is clicked it doesn't seem like it is doing anything. I tried to set the button to to Saving ... before it go to the saving file function then change it back after it is done. Even tried to show a progress dialog but it shows up after the function is done. How can I get the text to change or progress dialog to show before the function starts?

```
fileExport.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        progress.setTitle(null);
        progress.setMessage("Saving Device...");
        progress.show();

        fileExport.setText("Saving.....");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        AlertDialog alert;

        if (delegate.export()) {   //save file
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setTitle("Export Successful");
            builder.setMessage("Your settings were exported successfully to " + AppDelegate.path + ".");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        } else {
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setTitle("Export Unsuccessful");
            builder.setMessage("Error! There was a problem exporting your settings. Please try again.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
        fileExport.setText("Export to File");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are putting both of these processes on the same thread. Which means it is not updating the text of the button until the file is finished saving. Look into asynchronous tasks http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AsynchronousTasks.html,
to do this as an AsyncTask (which is likely a better choice when you need to update the UI)

In your activity, create an instance of your Async class and execute.

```
SaveData save = new SaveData();
save.execute();
```

Subclass AsyncTask as a private class within your activity

```
private class SaveData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    // your background code here. Don't touch any UI components

    if(your code worked...)
        return true;                
    else
        return false;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
     //This is run on the UI thread so you can do as you wish here
     if(result)
         Toast successful
     else
         Toast unsuccessful
 }
}
```